# Redux Reducer - how can I save this state as object? (I'm getting "Parsing Error")

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

My code looks like this:

```
import { SAVE_SEARCH } from '../actions/index';

export default function (state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_SEARCH:
      return [...state, action.payloadTwo, action.payloadOne];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And I'm getting such result in my state:

[image]

It works, but this is an array. I want to change it to object, like so:

```
    case SAVE_SEARCH:
      return [...state, { action.payloadTwo: action.payloadOne }];
```

So searchTerm would be the key in the object, and the data will be save as object key values.

But this code gives me an error:
[image]

I know it is obvious for you. Why I can't code it like this? Why I'm getting "Parsing Error"?

---

**---------------**

**EDIT:**

***Many thanks to @marekful for his answer! Now it works!***

My action.js code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const SAVE_SEARCH = 'SAVE_SEARCH';

export function searchTest(query) {
  const githubApi = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${query}&sort=stars&order=desc`;
  const request = axios.get(githubApi);
  return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({ data: dataFromGithub }) => {
      dispatch({ type: SAVE_SEARCH, payloadOne: query, payloadTwo: dataFromGithub });
    });
  };
}
```

reducer code:

```
import { SAVE_SEARCH } from '../actions/index';

export default function (state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_SEARCH:
      const o = {};
      o[action.payloadOne] = action.payloadTwo;
      return [...state, o];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: remove **action.** in the property name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In object literals, keys can only be string literals (values can be object references): `{"someKey": object.property}`

You can, however, use object references or function return values as object keys using array notation (but it still has to be a string):

```
let o = {};
o[action.payloadTwo] = action.payloadOne;
return [...state, o];
```

Comment: Ok, but I think I didn't understand it fully, because now I'm getting this:  0 { [object Object]: "test" }

Comment: Ok, sorry, now it works, I will edit this in my question soon!

Answer (score 1):

with ES6 you could directly use:
return [...state, { [action.payloadTwo]: action.payloadOne] }];